# Definition of a splitting field of a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This is a basic question from the journal 'Mathematische Zeitschrift' 208 (1991) page 243.

Let $K/F$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields and $G={\rm Gal}(K/F)$. Also let $L$ be any number field, $E$ a finite Galois extension of $L$. The article then states that $E$ is assumed to *split* $G$.

**Question:** What does it mean by a field *splitting* a group?

Comment: The group ring EG should be a direct product of matrix rings over E (rather than over division E-algebras). If G has order n, then adjoining the n'th roots of unity to L always produces a splitting field.

Comment: And you can do with adding only $e$th roots, with $e$ the exponent of the group.

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: I'm a bit confused- are you saying that $L$(all $n$th roots of $1$) is a splitting field of a certain polynomial in $L[X]$?

Comment: @user68418: sort of, yes. It is a splitting field of all the minimal polynomials of the matrices that might occur when G acts on a field. Each of those polynomials is a divisor of $x^n-1$ (indeed $x^e-1$ as in Mariano's comment), so you just need roots of unity. This will make sure that any eigenvalues already lie in $E$, and that even if you do more complicated things with $G$, it'll still happen "in E".

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: when you say that $G$ acts on a field, do you mean a representation of $G$ on a f.d. $L$-vector space? So are you considering all possible such representations?

Comment: yes and yes. if they only need some of the minimal polynomials to split (the ones where G is acting on some specific space V) then the phrase is "E is assumed to split G's action on V" or "V splits over E as a G-module".

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: I see. Let's see if I understood this correctly: so regardless of how many representations $V$ of $G$ there might be (possibly infinitely many), $L$(all $n$ th roots of $1$ in $E$) is a subfield of $E$ which is a splitting field of all the possible minimal polynomials that can occur from the induced $G$-action, and we call $E$ a splitting field of $G$ in this case.

Comment: @user68418: yes, exactly (assuming E itself was a splitting field). It's pretty cool that it works.